# Is "Mass Aid" spell level balanced, especially when compared to other "Mass" spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, balance

Mass Aid is a level 3 spell (it can be found in Spell Compendium page 8) and the base (non-mass) spell [Aid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/aid.htm) is a level 2 spell. This is just a +1 difference.

All other Mass spells have about +4 levels to basic versions, not +1.
For example, cure light wounds is level 1 and the mass version is level 5, same with moderate serious and critical cures, and they all have a limit 1 target per lvl too.

Mass Aid also does not have a limitation of one target per caster level (RAW) like most other spells.

One could say Aid is [single target] Bless plus a preemptive Cure Light Wounds. Aid is also comparable to False Life, a lvl 2 mage spell. I think the extra hitpoints of Aid is a lot more important than the paltry bonuses of Bless at low levels (when some characters have really low hitpoints and can't survive even a few AoE damage). But still compared to Mass Cure Light Wounds, Mass Aid seems way underleveled.

Is there a reason it's so wacky?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46407/discussion-between-korvinstarmast-and-simanos).

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this isn't asking for something objective, like designer statements. You might want a logic-based analysis, but that's also ripe for primarily opinion-based disagreements, and those arguments have already started happening here—so it's closed. (NB it's not just mods who've closed it.)

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply because *aid* isn’t a very good spell, and more to the point, it scales poorly. The attack bonus is small and the damage bonus is paltry; the bonus on saves against fear may very well be forgotten entirely. It also grants very few temporary HP, and temporary HP aren’t really particularly good protection.

Realistically, *aid* shouldn’t have been a 2nd-level spell to begin with. As a 1st-level spell, it’d be mediocre but possibly worth preparing (and it is probably too good for an orison).